# A series that converges to two different results

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone give me an example of a series that converges to two different results if we use two different ways to solve it? also, is there a series that would converge if we use one method to solve it and diverge if we use another method?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Alternating_harmonic_series

Comment: If a series converges, it converges. That's all that needs to be said. If it has subsequences that converge to two different results, it doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

Read @Don Thousand's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225018/a-series-that-converges-to-two-different-results#comment6635160_3225018):

> If a series converges, it converges. That's all that needs to be said. If it has subsequences that converge to two different results, it doesn't converge.

That being said, it's worth mentioning that there are methods to solve convergent series which, if applied to divergent series, would give unexpected results. For example, playing around with $S = 1-1+1-1+...$ could give $0$, or $1$ (or other values too):
$$\begin{align}
 S &= (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + 1 - 1 + \cdots &= 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 0 \\
 S &= 1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + \cdots &=  1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 1
\end{align}$$

Interestingly, by rearranging the order of the terms, some series can be made to converge to *any* real number. This is called the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)
.